# Drag down excel formula for with the same range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a worksheet in Excel that has several keywords with their search volumes, ranked by cities. So, there is about 74 lines for each city, something like this:

```
keyword 1 searchvolume 7000 city y
keyword 2 searchvolume 8000 city y
keyword 3 searchvolume 5000 city y
...
keyword 74 searchvolume 6000 city y
```

And below city y, there is another city with the samme pattern:

```
keyword 1 searchvolume 7000 city x
keyword 2 searchvolume 8000 city x
keyword 3 searchvolume 5000 city x
...
keyword 74 searchvolume 6000 city x
```

And then, in another worksheet, I need to sum and group the search volume of these cities. So, I have an "If city = X, sum(P2:P75)" and that works fine for one city. But if I drag down the Formula, it changes to sum(P3:P76).

What I need is to drag the formula for the same range for those 74 keywords, to get the whole city. So when I drag down the formula I need something like "from P2:P75" to "P76:P149". And then "P150:223"

Comment: It's hard for me to visualize your problem, but I assume you could use `SUMIFS()` to do a conditional sum.

Comment: Thank you friend @Marc! I was trying to do the sum the other way but this formula helped me. Thank you very much!